# How to add value to registry in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, registry

I can add value to registry from CMD, but when i do the same command with `os.system()`:

```
import os
os.system("REG ADD "
          "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce "
          "/t REG_SZ /v test /d C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\xxxxx.exe"
          )
```

This code returns `0`, which according to `REG /?` means that it worked, but I can't find the new value in `RunOnce`

Also this is my first time working with the registry :/

Update:

i tried fixing it with `os.popen()`, but no luck, am i doing this right?

```
os.popen('REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce" /v "test" /t REG_SZ /f /d "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\XXXX.exe"')
```